# Bootstrap Dropdown menu inside Grid.MVC cell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, helper, grid.mvc

I'm trying to render a dropdown menu with 6 options inside a Grid.MVC cell.
This [example](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Render%20button%2C%20checkbox%20etc%20in%20the%20grid%20cell) is very straightforward: you define an helper which generates the relevant markup.

This is my code:

```
@helper menuContestuale(int idEvento) { 
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&raquo;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Dettaglio", "DettaglioErrore/" + idEvento, "Home")
        </li>
       <li>
           @Html.ActionLink("Elimina anomalia", "EliminaErrore/" + idEvento, "Home")
       </li>
       <li>
           @Html.ActionLink("Elimina anomalie simili di questa persona", "EliminaSimiliPersona/" + idEvento, "Home")
       </li>
       <li>
           @Html.ActionLink("Elimina anomalie stesso processo di questa persona", "EliminaSimiliPersonaProcesso/" + idEvento, "Home")
       </li>
       <li>
           @Html.ActionLink("Elimina anomalie simili", "EliminaSimili/" + idEvento, "Home")
       </li>
       <li>
           @Html.ActionLink("Elimina intero processo", "EliminaProcesso/" + idEvento, "Home")
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
}

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(row => row.idEvento).RenderValueAs(row => menuContestuale(row.idEvento).ToHtmlString()).Encoded(false);
});
```

The resulting HTML in the table cell has most tags stripped away.

```
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="idEvento">    
    &raquo;</a>
        <li>
            Dettaglio</a>
        </li>
       <li>
           Elimina anomalia</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           Elimina anomalie simili di questa persona</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           Elimina anomalie stesso processo di questa persona</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           Elimina anomalie simili</a>
       </li>
       <li>
           Elimina intero processo</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

The same helper, called outside the Grid, returns correct markup.
Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you also need to call "Sanitized":

```
.Encoded(false).Sanitized(false)
```

Sanitizer is responsible for stripping potentially dangerous HTML tags from the string, so it could be the one removing them in your case.